# Type-safe Euclidean vectors in C++

Tags: c++, coordinate-system, raytracing

I'm trying to follow the [Raytracing in One Weekend](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1_MZBMUSO25pg1gyeHa_D8WXu7r37CvC6) book, and I found that he uses the same `Vec3` class for everything - colors, coordinates, direction, and more:

```
struct Vec3 { float x, y, z };
```

He also overloads every possible operator of the `Vec3` class to make it convenient to use, and adds plenty of member functions (`length`, `distance_to`, etc). While this definitely reduces the amount of code one has to write, it isn't terribly safe, and allows for things doesn't make sense (why would you want a `distance_to` between two `Color`s?). I was trying to fix that.

I defined a base Vector type:

```
struct Vector {
  Vector(float, float, float);

  float x;
  float y;
  float z;

  float length() const;
};
```

According to the [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euclidean_vector#Overview) page, there can be 2 types of vectors - bound vectors (goes from point A to point B) and free vectors (the particular point is of no significance, only the magnitude and direction are). I defined these types too, but with very limited operators.

Notice how you can add a `FreeVector` to a `BoundVector` to give a `BoundVector`, but you cannot add 2 `BoundVectors`:

```
struct BoundVector : public Vector {
  BoundVector(float, float, float);

  BoundVector& operator+=(const FreeVector&);
  BoundVector& operator-=(const FreeVector&);

  FreeVector operator-(const BoundVector&) const;
};

struct FreeVector : public Vector {
  FreeVector(float, float, float);
  explicit FreeVector(const UnitVector&);

  FreeVector& operator+=(const FreeVector&);
  FreeVector& operator-=(const FreeVector&);

  FreeVector& operator*=(float);
  FreeVector& operator/=(float);

  UnitVector unit() const;
  float dot(const FreeVector&) const;
};

BoundVector operator+(BoundVector, const FreeVector&);
BoundVector operator-(BoundVector, const FreeVector&);

FreeVector operator+(FreeVector, const FreeVector&);
FreeVector operator-(FreeVector, const FreeVector&);

FreeVector operator*(FreeVector, float);
FreeVector operator/(FreeVector, float);
```

I would have liked the `UnitVector` class to extend the `FreeVector` (or even the `Vector`) class, but I can't, since the implementation is completely different. For starters, to ensure that it is guaranteed to be a unit vector (`x*x + y*y + z*z == 1`) I have to make all members `const`:

```
struct UnitVector {
  UnitVector(float, float, float);
  explicit UnitVector(const FreeVector&);

  const float x;
  const float y;
  const float z;

  FreeVector operator*(float) const;
  FreeVector operator/(float) const;

 private:
  UnitVector(float, float, float, float);
};

UnitVector::UnitVector(const float x, const float y, const float z)
  : UnitVector(x, y, z, std::sqrt(x * x + y * y + z * z)) {}

UnitVector::UnitVector(const FreeVector& v) : UnitVector(v.x, v.y, v.z) {}

FreeVector UnitVector::operator*(const float k) const {
  return FreeVector(x * k, y * k, z * k);
}

FreeVector UnitVector::operator/(const float k) const {
  return FreeVector(x / k, y / k, z / k);
}

UnitVector::UnitVector(const float x, const float y, const float z, const float r)
  : x{x / r}, y{y / r}, z{z / r} {}
```

`UnitVectors` allow you to define directions in a much better manner:

```
struct Ray {
  BoundVector source;
  UnitVector direction;

  BoundVector parametric_eq(float) const;
};

BoundVector Ray::parametric_eq(const float t) const {
  return source + direction * t;
}
```

However, this is not all sunshine and roses, as it sometimes results in very ugly-looking `static_cast`s:

```
struct Lambertian : public Material {
  FreeVector albedo;
  std::optional<Scatter> scatter(const Ray&, const Strike&) const override;
};

FreeVector random_in_unit_sphere() {
  std::random_device r;
  std::default_random_engine gen(r());
  std::uniform_real_distribution<float> distribution(0, 1);

  while (true) {
    const FreeVector v(distribution(gen), distribution(gen), distribution(gen));
    if (v.length() < 1) return v;
  }
}

std::optional<Scatter> Lambertian::scatter(const Ray& ray,
                                           const Strike& strike) const {
  return Scatter{.attenuation = albedo,
                 .scattered = Ray{.source = strike.point,
                                  .direction = static_cast<UnitVector>(
                                      static_cast<FreeVector>(strike.normal) +
                                      random_in_unit_sphere())}};
}
```

Note that the `std::optional` is added here because the material may choose to absorb the `Ray` completely with some probability, and hence not scatter it at all.

Is there a way to reduce the number of `static_cast`s in the last example (or at least the overhead due to them)?

Any other feedback, comments and nitpickings are also welcomed.

Comment: designated initializers are a very nice feature of C++20... but we're in 2018! I'm not even sure which compilers do support it already

Comment: Strangely, CMake didn't support it so I couldn't use `set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 2a)`, but GCC stopped complaining once I added `set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} -std=c++2a)` to the CMakeLists.txt file.

Comment: From a purely mathematical point of view, a bounded vector is in fact a pair of two free vectors. Try to model your classes with that in mind. A mathematical point of view could be very helpful.

Comment: I did explore that option too, but I eventually settled for this (all bound vectors relative to the origin) because the bounded vectors were more space efficient (and even a little boost in efficiency really matters when you're doing raytracing). Although, in most cases, they are bound to the origin, in some cases in the book itself you come across a situation where the 2 free vector representation would have been helpful (such as the Camera class). In such cases, I used one bound vector position and a free vector to denote the direction taken from there.

Comment: Is it intentional that we're missing the definitions of the the free functions declared immediately after `FreeVector`?

Comment: @TobySpeight yep, since the implementation is rather obvious, and including it would lengthen the answer considerably. Instead, I put in the function prototypes to convey what _operations_ are possible. If need be, I can include that too.

Comment: That's fine - I didn't want to answer if you needed to edit the question.  BTW, there are subtleties to even such simple functions - I've seen implementations that do more copying than is necessary, for example.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## Consider a typedef instead of hardcoding `float` everywhere

Whilst the current use-case requires `float`, we might want to convert to a template in future, so that we could use with `double` or `long double`.  We can ease that by defining a type alias, so there's less work to change when we do so:

```
using value_type = float;
```

## Consider implementing unary minus

If we implement unary `operator-()` for `FreeVector`, we can use that to implement subtraction in terms of addition (without loss of efficiency).

## Use standard Euclidean-length function

Instead of writing `std::sqrt(x * x + y * y + z * z)`, we could use `std::hypot()` instead for an algorithm that remains stable for very large and very small values.  Since C++17, there's an overload that takes all three inputs:

```
float Vector::length() const {
    return std::hypot(x, y, z);
}
```

## Could `UnitVector` be implemented using `FreeVector`?

Instead of having constant members (which of course inhibits assignment operators), perhaps it's worthwhile having a private `FreeVector` member in a `UnitVector`, and forwarding access?  Something like this:

```
struct UnitVector
{
    UnitVector(float x, float y, float z);
    explicit UnitVector(const FreeVector& other);

    operator const FreeVector&() const { return v; }

private:
    FreeVector v;
};

UnitVector::UnitVector(const float x, const float y, const float z)
    : UnitVector{FreeVector{x, y, z}}
{}

UnitVector::UnitVector(const FreeVector& v)
    : v{v / v.length()}
{}
```

Note that I've provided a non-explicit conversion to `FreeVector`, as a replacement for the `FreeVector(UnitVector)` constructor.  This means that we no longer need to implement arithmetic operators for `UnitVector`, as they will simply promote to `FreeVector` in such contexts.

## Document the behaviour of indefinite unit vectors

What happens when we try to create a unit vector when its length is zero?  I think we end up with all NaNs - we should make it clearer to users what they should expect (without them having to read the implementation).  We might even need an `operator bool()` that tests whether any element of the vector is NaN.

## Style - give names to formal parameters

It's subjective, but I think it makes an interface easier to read if the formal parameters have names, particularly when there are multiple arguments of the same type.

## Kudos

I often forget to give this, so: well done on good use of `const` and `explicit`; I was pleased to see that the binary operations take one argument by copy and one by const-ref, so the copy can be modified and returned.

Comment: While I had considered the type alias, I wasn't sure whether to add `float` or `value_type` to parameters and return types. In case of a change, won't there be external functions that rely on having to work with a `float` that are suddenly forced to use whatever the new `value_type` is aliased to? Also, is `value_type` a standard naming practice, and should I be namespacing it to `geometry::value_type`? If yes, should I namespace everything else too?

Comment: You're right - the `UnitVector` divison by zero does give `NaN`. How would you suggest handling this?

Comment: My suggestion is to provide the means to test whether the `UnitVector` is valid, and then leave it up to the user to check.  But you could choose to throw an exception instead.  You'll have to choose which best suits your users.  As for `value_type`, as long as that's an alias of `float`, no change required by users - even when `Vector` becomes a template (provided the type defaults to `float`).